# Mix it up is not working in tab1 but working in another tab i.e tab2 in chrome and mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixitup

on document ready code to call mixitup function

```
if ($('.tab1').hasClass('active')) {
    initialize_mixitup('#mixitup_image_search_gallery', '#switchtogrid', '#switchtolist', '.mix_image', '.image_sort', 'grid', '');
}
$(".tab2").click(function () {
    initialize_mixitup('#your_books_image_gallery', '#yourbook_switchtogrid', '#yourbook_switchtolist', '.mix_book', '.book_sort', 'grid', '');
});


function initialize_mixitup(mixitup_container, grid_button, list_button, target_class, sort_class, default_layout, mix_callback) {
var layout = default_layout,
        $mixitupContainer = $(mixitup_container),
        $gridButton = $(grid_button),
        $listButton = $(list_button);

$mixitupContainer.mixItUp({
    selectors: {target: target_class, sort: sort_class},
    animation: {animateChangeLayout: true, animateResizeTargets: true, effects: 'fade rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(-100px)'},
    layout: {containerClass: default_layout},
    callbacks: mix_callback
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by replacing the container Id of both the containers with container class.

Answer (score 0):

Just from this quick look, does your tab1 have a click event defined like tab2?
example:

```
$(".tab1").click(function () {
    initialize_mixitup('#your_books_image_gallery', '#yourbook_switchtogrid', '#yourbook_switchtolist', '.mix_book', '.book_sort', 'grid', '');
});
```

Comment: tab1 have a click event but it is still not working.